# Why does PowerShell's Start-Job sometimes finish without executing code?

Tags: powershell, start-job, scriptblock

I have been investigating an issue we see in some deployments at work.

For background, we have multiple services deploying into Azure, and there is one main script which uses `Start-Job` to run concurrent sub-jobs. Most of the time this worked, although occasionally we saw builds where a sub-job reported as completed, but its `HasMoreData` attribute was `false`, and no errors showed up anywhere. No sub-job that we run could complete successfully without at least having one line of logs, so this appears to be an error with starting the job.

This is the command we used to create the jobs:

```
Start-Job -Name $RepoName -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command "$args"} -ArgumentList $command
```

During discussions we thought possibly there was an error, but that the `Invoke-Expression` was eating it, so we changed the job creation to instead be:

```
Start-Job -Name $RepoName -ScriptBlock ([ScriptBlock]::Create(".{$command}"))
```

Since making that change yesterday we have not seen this issue re-appear. To test I created a new branch where I reverted back to the `Invoke-Expression` method and immediately began seeing the error again.

I was just hoping to see if anyone might have an idea about why this issue might be appearing, and why it is an intermittent problem when using the Invoke-Expression method, but not the `[ScriptBlock]::Create` method.

Thank you!

Edit for further background:

So the main script (deployAll.ps1) has a list of services to deploy and for each one it builds up a command to execute, which builds the necessary environment, then calls a deployService.ps1 script provided by each service.

Regarding building the command to execute, we have a common script all the sub-jobs use, so we import that and login to Azure as part of the command we build up, so the command that actually gets passed to Start-Job looks something like:

`Import-Module $ScriptPath\AzureWrapper.ps1 -Force; $ScriptPath\login.ps1 -AzureAppID $Env:AZURE_APP_ID -AzurePassword $Env:AZURE_PASSWORD -AzureTenantId $Env:AZURE_TENANT_ID; $ScriptPath\..\$RepoName\deploy\deployService.ps1 -subscriptionId '$subscriptionId' -environmentFilePath '$configPath'`

Additionally, after looking into `Invoke-Expression` further it seems it may have been the reason those setup commands were necessary, since it runs in a separate environment.

Comment: `$args` is an automatic variable and `Invoke-Expression` is a dangerous cmdlet that you shouldn't use in general.  It could be possible `$args` isn't being populated properly.  You could test this by adding a line outputting the value in the scriptblock before `iex`

Comment: I think my question here is why are you trying to indiscriminately run powershell commands through jobs?

Comment: Thanks for the response! We are calling subscripts to run deployments, but need to do some environment setup ahead of time for authentication.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit enter too soon there, continuation:
So the main script (deployAll.ps1) has a list of services to deploy and for each one it builds up a command to execute, which builds the necessary environment, then calls a deployService.ps1 script provided by each service.

Comment: What do you mean "builds up a command"?  Could you give an example? (preferably in your question)

Comment: I edited my question with the information I provided in these comments, as well as an example command.